# How to organize HTML for faster and easier editing?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on making a task list using html, take a look [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/gr8_boi52/bQM9s/)

(please edit this link for me)

I get frustrated when i have to find the task code every time and change it.

Is there a way to organize my work? for example. if I want to change task 3, there will be a separated file for that or something and i have to only change that and it will take effect on the main file. Sorry i am bad at explaining things. comment if you need more info

Code example

```
<!--content1 here-->
<li>
blah blah blah 
</li>
<!--content2 here-->
<li>
blah blah blah 
</li>
<!--content3 here-->
<li>
blah blah blah 
</li>
<!--content4 here-->
<li>
blah blah blah 
</li>
```

Comment: links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code - stackoverflow.com

Comment: please fix your fiddle, put script in the up left square, html down left, etc

Comment: fixed a typo in the fiddle :)

Comment: If you can't provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), this is most likely not the right place to ask.

Comment: i can't edit the fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can accomplish this.

If you're willing to learn some server-side scripting language such as PHP, Ruby, or Python, you could split your HTML files up into several smaller ones, and combine them together using something like [PHP includes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Some webservers also include something called [Server side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) which are a tad simpler, and may be easier to setup.

Alternatively, if you know some programming language, and don't have a server, you could write a short script which manually takes your HTML files and combines them together. However, this is probably a way more complicated solution then you need.

And if none of these work, you could check if your code editor lets you mark lines (for example, if you click on the left margin in Notepad++, it'll leave a blue circle by the line number) or fold code. That way, you could just scroll quickly to the part you need, or hide code you're not working on.

Comment: thanks, that kinda helped out.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question will probably be closed as its potentially opinion based, I'd recommend using [PHP includes](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/include.php), that way you can keep content pages separate from the code forming your, for example, index page.

Comment: You don't need PHP for this. Server-side includes in plain HTML would suffice.